# Python: time difference between columns which has blanks, causes error

Tags: python, pandas

learning py pandas and cannot solve the time subtraction problem..
I want to find the time difference between two columns.
quite simple....

df['TimeDiff'] = (df['LogOut'] - df['LogIn'])

causes **"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'"**

I guess, this error is caused as some time stamps are empty...
But cannot be sure as I am new to python...

The table image is here [Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuVGs.png)

Please advise.

Comment: This is happening because `df['LogOut']` ,`df['LogIn']` are of type `str` so firstly change them  in `timestamp` or `datetime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
df['LogOut'] = pd.to_datetime(df['LogOut'])
df['LogIn'] = pd.to_datetime(df['LogIn'])
```

This will convert the columns to datetime, which is supported.

You can also look into the package `timedelta`

Comment: Yes and then try ```df['TimeDiff'] = (df['LogOut'] - df['LogIn'])``` again.

Comment: Your option caused: 
ParserError: String does not contain a date: 

P.S. strange as these two columns do have nothing but timestamps... or are empty 
;(

Comment: I would assume that a row value is empty, you can do ```df['col name'].fillna("value")``` and then try to convert to ```datetime```.

Answer (score 0):

The excel sheet LogIN/Out columns were protected...

So I saved file in .csv and found that empty cells were actually Not blank, they contain 8 spaces each

Tried:
df['LogOut'].replace(" ", "")

df['LogOut'].fillna("0")

and the last...

df['LogOut'] = pd.to_datetime(df['LogOut'])

caused the same error... (ParserError: String does not contain a date:)...

Answer (score 0):

took awhile...

empty cells were causing the problem.

the fix is

df['LogOut'] = pd.to_datetime(df['LogOut'], errors='coerce')